# Adding buttons to top and bottom of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a screen displaying all the matches I'm currently in, in my turn-based game. I am using a table view with 3 sections for this.

Now I want to add a button 'start new game' to the top above the displaying games. Below the displaying games I want a few buttons like 'shop' etc. I can place them but then they won't scroll along so I need to put them in the tableview so they scroll along.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: header and footer views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where you want your button, but UITableView have a
`@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView`
If you want it to be on the top of your tableView and scroll with it, just make the view you want and put it in that property.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *headerContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, X, X, X)];
UIButton *btnHeader = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[headerContainer addSubview:btnHeader];


UIView *footerContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, X, X, X)];
UIButton *btnFooter = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[footerContainer addSubview:btnFooter];


tblView.tableHeaderView = headerContainer;
tblView.tableFooterView = footerContainer;
```

Answer (score 1):

UITableView has a tableHeaderView and a tableFooterView property. You can set this value for your custom view.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableHeaderView;                            // accessory view for above row content. default is nil. not to be confused with section header
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableFooterView;                            // accessory view below content. default is nil. not to be confused with section footer
```

Note: when you set your custom view to tableHeaderView/tableFooterViewn property, its width will be changed as wide as table view's

Answer (score 1):

add UIbutton to Navigation controller view like this code:

```
let createButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height-50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
createButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
createButton.setTitle("Create", for: UIControlState())
createButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCreate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(createButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that much clear.. in tableview we we gave a propertys
property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableHeaderView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableFooterView;

and even you can checkout this

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

you can added your view here too.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

this you can use for the height between the sections